# Как поместить linearlayout в самый низ экрана

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-linearlayout

Пытаюсь поместить linearlayout в самый низ экрана. На предпросмотре все работает нормально, однако на реальном устройстве он находится в самом верху экрана. XML код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/homeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/Total"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="156dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Total:"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="135dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:background="@drawable/scanbutton"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="156dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Может ли эта проблема быть связанна с тем, что мы работаем с фрагментом?
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener 
    {

```
    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initView(view);
    }

    private void initView(View view){
        AppCompatImageButton imageButton1 = (AppCompatImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imageButton1.setOnClickListener(this);

        AppCompatButton imageButton2 = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        imageButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void changeFragment1(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScannerActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void changeFragment2(){

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout,new 
SubHome1Fragment()).commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                changeFragment1();
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                changeFragment2();
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Вам следовало бы приложить скриншоты, т.к. представлять вашу проблему только по xml коду - затруднительно. Второе, я настоятельно рекомендовал бы вам использовать ConstraintLayout - это значительно облегчит верстание xml-страниц во всем приложении.

Comment: Почему? Мне просто интересно зачем их использовать, если есть RelativeLayour?

Comment: Constraint позволяют удобнее, а главное нагляднее верстать дизайн, дабы избежать таких проблем.

Comment: RelativeLayout уже находится в разделе Legacy. Хотя бы поэтому от его использования в новых приложениях стоит воздержаться.